# array_push created array is acting strangely. When attempting to output associative array value returns first letter of Array or "A"

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to use a foreach to output the array below. I have created this array via array_push() based on preg_match if/else.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [date] => 
        [clickurl] => some data
        [url] => some data
        [dispurl] => some Data...
        [title] => Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen : Reviews
        [abstract] => "Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen" is a horrible experience of unbearable length, briefly punctuated by three or four amusing moments.
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [date] => 
        [clickurl] => some data
        [url] => some data
        [dispurl] => some Data...
        [title] => Transformers : Reviews
        [abstract] => After a string of bad-to-mediocre films, director Michael Bay scores with blockbuster battling robots in "Transformers."
    )
)
```

When attempting to output the array:

```
foreach ($reviewArr as $review) {
    echo($review['clickurl']. '<br/><br/>');
}
```

The output is "A" which is the first letter of Array at the start of the array above. This is the same result as using `$review[0];`

When using:

```
foreach ($reviewArr as $review) {
    echo($review. '<br/><br/>');
}
```

the output is:

```
Array ( 
    [date] => 
    [clickurl] => some data 
    [url] => some data
    [dispurl] => some data... 
    [title] => Transformers : Reviews 
    [abstract] => After a string of bad-to-mediocre films, director Michael Bay scores with blockbuster battling robots in "Transformers." 
)
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

UPDATE =

This is the original Array that I parse below to split into two different arrays.

```
Array
    (
[bossresponse] => Array
    (
        [responsecode] => 200
        [web] => Array
            (
                [start] => 0
                [count] => 14
                [totalresults] => 14
                [results] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                                [clickurl] => http://url.com/1
                                [url] => http://url.com/1
                                [dispurl] => http://url.com/1...
                                [title] => Title of Content 1
                                [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,    This is the summary, ...
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                                [clickurl] => http://url.com/2
                                [url] => http://url.com/2
                                [dispurl] => http://url.com/2...
                                [title] => Title of Content 2
                                [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,  This is the summary, ...
                            )
                    )

              )

       )

)
```

This is how I am setting the $reviewArr[].

```
foreach ($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $key => $result) {
                $url = $result['clickurl'];
                $title = $result['title'];
                $abstract = $result['abstract'];
                $resultItem = print_r($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'][$key], true);
                if (preg_match ("/reviews/i", "$url")) {
                    array_push($reviewArr, "$resultItem");
                } else {
                    array_push($resultsArr, "$resultItem");
                }
            }
```

UPDATE #2 -

I see thanks to @fabio that I am simply setting a string with `$resultItem` above. How can I achieve creating a multidimensional array? How can I build this as an array - all of my attempts returned errors, or a string.

```
 Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                                [clickurl] => http://url.com/1
                                [url] => http://url.com/1
                                [dispurl] => http://url.com/1...
                                [title] => Title of Content 1
                                [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,    This is the summary, ...
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [date] => 
                                [clickurl] => http://url.com/2
                                [url] => http://url.com/2
                                [dispurl] => http://url.com/2...
                                [title] => Title of Content 2
                                [abstract] => This is the summary, This is the summary,  This is the summary, ...
                            )
                    )
```

Comment: Can you add the output you get from `var_dump($reviewArr);` to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant, I am in a basterdized environment, that is through WSH. I can do print_r since it has the true which will return the result, so I have to set it to a variable and then echo out the variable.

Comment: @NullUserException:  We would have cancelled each other out as that almost got an up vote from me.

Comment: What does print_r look like then?

Comment: That is what I have at the top of the page in my initial question/post. That is the print_r output copy and pasted.

Comment: I think you should close this question, accept an answer and open a new one for asking your new question. This is becoming too messy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
foreach ($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $key => $result) {
    $url = $result['clickurl'];
    $title = $result['title'];
    $abstract = $result['abstract'];
    $resultItem = print_r($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'][$key], true);
    if (preg_match ("/reviews/i", "$url")) {
        array_push($reviewArr, "$resultItem");
    } else {
        array_push($resultsArr, "$resultItem");
    }
}
```

to:

```
foreach ($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'] as $key => $result) {
    if (preg_match ("/reviews/i", $result['clickurl'])) {
        $reviewArr[] = $result;
    } else {
        $resultsArr[] = $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the original question with how I am setting the array...I am assuming its the fact that I am using print_r?? I tried a ton of things and failed up until doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are pushing items on your array, but I think this could do the trick:

```
foreach ($reviewArr as $index=>$review) {
    echo($review['clickurl']. '<br/><br/>');
}
```

Comment: This would do the exact same thing.  Iterating over the keys and values while not using the key is the same as just iterating over the values.

Comment: I can concur with @sberry2A that the above is what I initially was using. This also outputs the single "A" from the Array at the beginning of `$reviewArr`

Answer (score 0):

For what weird reason are you filling the array with the return value of print_r???

```
// this will return a string
$resultItem = print_r($results['bossresponse']['web']['results'][$key], true);
```

So here is the reason of your behaviour: you're printing the first character of the [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) return value which is the string representation of `$results[...][...]` array.

Try it by yourself

```
$foo = "Hello world";
echo $foo[0]; // output H
```

P.S. `echo($review. '<br/><br/>');` will output the whole string which is the print_r output.

Comment: Thank you @Fabio for the reply. I was trying to use `$results['bossresponse']['web']['results'][$key]` to build the new multidimensional array but it didn't work. Can you please offer any pointers on how I can assign to the new array?

Comment: You're in a foreach and can use `$result` as the whole subarray. Your `preg_match` need to run against `$result['url']` and you should assign it to another array with `array_push($reviews, $result)`. You should read some PHP tutorial about arrays ;-)